# Where would Git pull make changes if a folder has been renamed and then recreated?

Tags: git

I had a folder tristanisanoob that i renamed to tristanisanoob-2019 I then unzipped file that recreated folder tristanisanoob

If I git pull changes made remotely to files in tristanisanoob will be applied to which local folder?

Comment: First, git doesn't track folders per se, it tracks file paths. Pulling would most likely result in a merge conflict since the pull affects a path that no longer exists in your local repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull origin master` is simply a `git fetch origin` to update your copy of the remote, plus a `git merge origin/master`. So the question is what happens when you merge?

As mentioned by Rudedog, Git does not track folders, only their files. The changes will be applied to files in `tristanisanoob` and there will likely be conflicts.

You can try this out by cloning your own repository and playing around.

```
git clone /path/to/my/repo
```